# Creating a 1-D Numpy array and appending an element similar to list in python

Tags: python, numpy

```py
import numpy as np

data = [.02,.033,.044,.0789]

a  = np.array([0])

for i in range(len(data)):
   elem = data[i]
   a = np.insert(a, i,elem)
```

Desired Outcome:

a = [.02,.033,.044,.0789]

Comment: Is there any difference with `np.array(data)`?

Comment: well, I am trying to see if I can implement a 1-d numpy array and append values from there. there are similar ways to turn the list itself into an array, but I am seeking the first approach than the second. But thanks anyways :)

Comment: how about a[i] = data[i] ? in your for loop... or without for loop maybe simple a=data.copy()

Comment: Why?  Repeatedly adding to an array is inefficient.  It makes a whole new array each time.  If you must work iteratively, stick with lists.  The core operation for making a new array from several arrays is `np.concatenate`.  Read it's docs, and learn to pay attention to dimensions.